# App Insights Logs my kusto function not displayed in function list

Tags: azure-application-insights, azureportal

I have created a new Kusto function in Application Insights -> logs -> Query Editor and saved my query in Shared Query, but I still could not able to see Fx icon near to my query and its not listed in function list, is it something related to my acces permission?
[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you save it, you should select "Function" rather than "Query".

[image]